# How do I remove a delay created using dm-delay?

Tags: linux, centos, device-mapper

As part of testing my application, I wanted to see what would happen on hard-disk slow down or failure. I added a 500ms delay using `dmsetup create delayed`. I'm not very familiar with device mapper, and I can't find any answers online. How do I safely remove delay from a block device?

The output of lsblk on my VM is as follows:

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                 2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                 8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1              8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2              8:2    0 59.5G  0 part
  └─delayed       253:16   0 59.5G  0 dm
    ├─centos-root 253:0    0 38.6G  0 lvm  /
    ├─centos-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
    └─centos-home 253:2    0 18.9G  0 lvm  /home
```

My worry is that I'll cause disk instability if any writes occur when the mount is being removed .

Comment: dmsetup remove delayed

Comment: `dmsetup remove delayed` in the event it still shows in table and is cleared with a reboot  try `dmsetup clear delayed`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put back the original linear mapping(s) that were presumably at that point or rewrite your delay to be 0. In short look at your delay entry using `dmsetup table delayed` and think about how to turn it into a `linear` entry / use a delay of 0, replace it with the appropriate entry using `dmsetup reload delayed` etc. and then run `dmsetup resume delayed` to make it take effect.